# mysql query to join two tables of closing ,opening stock and recived stock

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb-10.5

need help with MySQL query to join one table has closing & opening stock and another table has received the stock.
what I want is to join column **recvd_value** from  table **recived** which stock purchase values to table **sales** which has an opening and closing stock values here is the [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=f719c3acebb5d20f40d718d5e20bb613)
what I want is this check this image ---> [Output I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YtVV.png)

[Table1 Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSy6v.png)

[table2 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZs0P.png)

this is my query

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    bar_recvd_details
        INNER JOIN
    bar_opening_details ON bar_recvd_details.item_id = bar_opening_details.item_id
WHERE
    bar_recvd_details.recvd_date = '2018-06-18'
        AND bar_opening_details.close_date = '2018-06-18';
```

Comment: Show desired output for provided fiddle. With detailed explanations. Sync tablenames between the fiddle and shown SQL.

Comment: @Akina hi there this is the output I want ,check this screenshot  [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tuv14.png)

Comment: @akina any help appreciated

Comment: Desired output should be formatted table, complete and without unclear arrows.

Comment: @Akina [check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YtVV.png) i want this output

Answer (score 0):

You can use **INNER JOIN** sql command for that.

```
SELECT sales.item_cid, sales.item_id, sales.op_value, sales.close_val, sales.close_date, recived.recvd_value 
FROM sales 
INNER JOIN recived ON recived.item_id = sales.item_id;
```

This query basically fetchs recvd_value from your recived table where 2 tables item_id's match.

Here's your fiddle:

[DBFiddle.Uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=4b922d8d9b2a2dad9b617703a384c412)

Screenshot from your Fiddle:

[image]

Comment: thank u for an answer but here I also want  **close_date**  column from sales and **recvd_date** from table recived  to match because the received stock can be any date but I must able to add that to sales table on that date

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/307556/248088   can u please look at this question for more clarity u can answer there only